# How to pass string from onListItemClick event to onButtonClick event of the same activity in android?

Tags: android

I have to pass value of a string variable once the the list item is clicked to button click event of the same activity so that i can use it's value.Actually the value is passed and i am able to see in a toast but if i try to display in textveiw .It does't show.Basically i want to check its value with sqlite database so i want its value.Pleas help me!!!

Comment: Please, paste your code so that we can see the context clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If the onListItemClick and onButtonClick are in the same java file, just set up a private variable in the activity class which can be written and read by your functions

Answer (score 0):

What about if you declare your value for the whole Activity, at the top of your class ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare that variable as static and try to get value.. Also declare the variable in your top of the Activity not inside any functions...